# Applying Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions seem to ignore Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

```
NDSolveValue[{-\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) == 
       NeumannValue[1., x == 5], 
     DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == 
     Piecewise[{{x, y == -1 || y == 1}, {x, x == 1 || x == -1}}], 
    True]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] 
    mesh];
Plot3D[%[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

From the code above resulting in this plot:
[image]

Where as my mesh looks like this: [image]

What I expected from the plot is that by setting the Neumann value to 1 on the edges, I would get an inclined plane (with a square hole). I suspect the Dirichlet condition is overriding and setting 0 everywhere on the boundary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wrong part of your code is :

```
DirichletCondition[
u[x, y] == Piecewise[{{x, y==-1 || y==1}, {x, x==1 || x==-1}}]
,True]
```

which should be something like :

```
DirichletCondition[
u[x, y] == x
, (-1.1 < x < 1.1) && (-1.1 < y < 1.1)]
```

The first argument of DirichletCondition specifies the value at the boundary. The second argument specifies where to apply the value. In fact it suffices to give a domain that contains the related boundary (and not the others boundaries).

By the way I have cleaned your code so that it becomes friendly in the StackExchange context :

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
region1 = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];
region2 = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
region = RegionDifference[region1, region2];
(*RegionPlot[region,ImageSize\[Rule]200]*)

mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.05];
(*Show[mesh["Wireframe"] ,ImageSize\[Rule]200]*)  

NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == NeumannValue[1., x == 5], 
        DirichletCondition[
    u[x, y] == x, (-1.1 < x < 1.1) && (-1.1 < y < 1.1)]}
  , u
  , Element[{x, y}, mesh]];
Plot3D[%[x, y], Element[{x, y}, mesh]]
```

[image]